# Minimizing the following objective function with matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are known matrices, and we are to find matrix $X$ that minimizes the following function,

$$\frac{1}{2}||X||^2+\frac{1}{2}||X^TAX-B||^2$$

Taking the relevant derivative w.r.t $X$ gives us,
$$ X +(X^TAX-B)(A+A^T)X$$

I couldn't reduce the derivative further as $A$ is not necessarily a square matrix; so, $(A+A^T)$ would be invalid. I am using the formula in slide 17, [Matrix Calculus](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/class/10725-S10/recitations/r4/Matrix_Calculus_Algebra.pdf) to differentiate $X^TAX$ to $(A+A^T)X$

Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: For the product $X^TAX$ to be defined, $A$ must be square. W.l.o.g. you can assume that $A$ is symmetric or replace it by its symmetrized version. I'm not sure that there is an easy solution. Try to find something usable in the case that $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. $A$ must be a square matrix, thanks. Now that this is out of the way, is it easy to solve for $X$ when equating the derivative to zero? thanks

Comment: No, not really. You can not even assume that one of the factors is zero, since there are non-zero matrices with product zero. -- If $A$ were positive definite, you could take a square root of it, a real square root, not just a Cholesky factor, and express the equation in terms of the matrix $Y=A^{1/2}XA^{1/2}$ as $$[I+2(Y^TY+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})]Y=0.$$ But is the derivative correct? Replace in the original objective function $X$ by $X+tH$ and compute the linear terms, I think $(A+A^T)X$ should come before $(X^TAX−B)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the AGM inequality, $\frac{1}{2}(||X||^2 + ||X^TAX - B||^2) \geq ||X||||X^TAX - B||$ with equality if $||X|| = ||X^TAX - B||$.  So the minimum occurs when $X = X^TAX - B$.

Comment: Thanks, but then how would we solve for $X$ here. $X=X^TAX-B$ => $B=X^TAX-X$   =>  $B=(X^TA-I)X$  => ??

Comment: Does the matrix $X$ have any special structure.  For example, is it self-adjoint, unitary, or invertible?

Comment: No, the structure of $X$ is completely arbitrary, but its numbers are Real.

Comment: Mustafa, you are clearly wrong because when the required minimum is reached for a matrix $X$, there's no reason so that your AGM inequality becomes an equality.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $X$ by $X+εH$ and disregard all terms that are $O(ε^2)$. Then, assuming the matrix norm is the Frobenius norm (?)
\begin{align}
&\tfrac12\|X+εH\|^2+\tfrac12\|(X+εH)^TA(X+εH)-B\|^2\\[1em]
&=\tfrac12\|X\|^2+ε\,Tr(X^TH)\\[0.2em]
&\qquad+\;\tfrac12\|X^TAX-B\|^2+ε\,Tr((X^TAX-B)^TH^TAX)+ε\,Tr((X^TAX-B)^TX^TAH)\\[1em]
&=\tfrac12\|X\|^2+\tfrac12\|X^TAX-B\|^2\\[0.2em]
&\qquad+ε\,Tr\Bigl(\Bigl[X^T+(X^TA^TX-B^T)X^TA+(X^TAX-B)X^TA^T\Bigr]H\Bigr)
\end{align}

So the correct derivative is 
$$
X^T+(X^TA^TX-B^T)X^TA+(X^TAX-B)X^TA^T
$$
or transposed as gradient
$$
X+A^TX(X^TAX-B)+AX(X^TA^TX-B^T)
$$
which has no easy further simplifications.